# symfony 3.4, dev environment?

Tags: php, symfony, routes, environment, symfony-3.4

I would like to learn symfony. For these purposes i've installed symfony 3.4 on my localhost.
Now I can not understand, why/how the app uses "dev" environment? There is a derictive in the web/.htaccess file: DirectoryIndex app.php  (not app_dev.php)
But it seems to be the "dev" environment ist active, because I see the debug toolbar on the page bottom (if I run localhost:8000/app.php I don't see the debug toolbar).
I thought it works as follow:  DirectoryIndex app.php in .htaccess -> app.php will be loaded -> $kernel = new AppKernel('**prod**', false); -> condig.yml will be loaded. But this is apparently wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will always read documentation before I ask dumb questions...

The answer is:  "...If you're using the built-in PHP web server, it knows to use the app_dev.php"